# jSlider code causes the application to hang

Tags: java, netbeans

This jSlider code causes the application to hang.

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:               
        try {
              for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
                {
            jSlider1.setValue(i);
            Thread.sleep(3000);
              }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AsdView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }              
}
```

thank you guys i am updating the answer

```
 Timer time = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
                  int percent = 0;

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        percent++;
                        if (percent>100)
                                percent = 0;

                     jSlider1.setValue((int)(100*(percent/600.0)));
                }
        });
        time.start();
```

Comment: It's spelled "why", not "y". Please no l33t-sp34k on SO.

Comment: Well you are sleeping for 3 seconds for each iteration of the loop for a total of 300 seconds (5 minutes!). May be that's why it appears hanging?

Comment: the slider should move right? like an progress bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you are trying to do some kind of smooth scroll.

That code freezes because the event thread that handles the window painting, sizing, etc..., is being frozen by you executing Thread.sleep(3000), 100 times.

I would recommend that you use a [Swing timer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) that changes the scroll bar little by little.

Comment: true can you give me an sample

Comment: Timer time = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
                  int percent = 0;

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        percent++;
                        if (percent>100)
                                percent = 0;
                      
                     jSlider1.setValue((int)(100*(percent/600.0)));
                }
        });
        time.start();

Answer (score 0):

i don't know why you put the sleep for 3 secs and that too in for loop of 100
3*100 = 5 mins so it will hang upto 5 mins
remove Thread.sleep(3000);

it will work fine and won't hang

Answer (score 0):

When you say your application 'hangs', that generally means that you have some sort of deadlock that prevents your threads from making progress.  Is that what you're observing in your program?  The way it's currently written, the current thread of execution will take at least 300 seconds to complete.  Is this work being done on the main thread of execution?  If so, you may want to consider creating a new Thread to do this work.